# logback-access with Restlet

Tags: jetty, slf4j, logback, restlet

I'm using logback-classic with my Restlet application (embedded Jetty), via the Restlet SLF4J bridge. For a variety of reasons we'd like our access logging to be done with logback-access, but I can't figure out how to get Restlet to behave with this package. Has anybody had success with this in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thierry Boileau created a great answer to this question with code included on the Restlet mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/a/restlet.org/forum/#!msg/framework-discuss/PP_88sK8Www/b0eyzhjoAAAJ

Answer (score 2):

Logback Access is no longer appropriate for Jetty 9.

If you can configure the Jetty `Server` object, then you can setup a [`RequestLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog.html) bean on the `Server` that uses the [`Slf4jRequestLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLog.html) implementation to write all access logging events to a ([configurable](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLog.html#setLoggerName-java.lang.String-)) named logger.

From there, just setup your logback configuration to write events on that specific named logger to the log file of your choice.

Eg:

```java
    Slf4jRequestLog requestlog = new Slf4jRequestLog();
    requestlog.setLoggerName("com.company.access.log");
    server.addBean(requestlog);
```

Comment: Restlet's Jetty extension seems pretty well designed to not give you access to the Jetty `Server` object

Comment: That seems counter intuitive.  How would you configure the connectors? the HttpConfiguration? the SSL/TLS negotiation layer?

Comment: You configure everything through Restlet, I guess Restlet probably passes the configuration to Jetty under the covers.